LightDM: Multi-Monitor setup and Resolution
I'm on Xubuntu 22.04 with a Dual-Monitor setup. Auto-login is enabled. The normal Monitor is FullHD (DVI), the TV is 4K (HDMI). In Xfce settings i use mirroring both are running with 1920x1080. The LightDM screen is displayed on the Monitor but with 4K Resolution. Because of that i can't see the window where i can enter the password. But the login works so there must be the login window somewhere where i can't see it. There is no login screen on the TV. My mainboard prefers the HDMI when i use both. I can't see the Bios when HDMI is connected.
I tried this in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
display-setup-script=xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080

but after reboot it doesn't work. Because of the auto-login there is no login screen while botting but when i logout i see the screen with 4k resolution.
I tried the same with a script:
display-setup-script=/usr/share/lightdmxrandr.sh

and this in the script (script is executable):
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080

Is there an other way to realize that?
